# mysql table to table sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to [update] the transaction_id from transactions table into the cmas table but I'm missing something... not sure where to reference the cmas table so it doesn't error `#1054 - Unknown column 'cmas.property_id' in 'where clause'`

```
INSERT INTO `cmas` (`transaction_id`)
SELECT `transaction_id`
FROM `transactions` WHERE transactions.property_id = cmas.property_id // this bit is wrong!
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you mention updates in the comments, this might be what you are looking for:

```
UPDATE cmas, transactions
SET cmas.transaction_id = transactions.transaction_id
WHERE transactions.property_id = cmas.property_id
```

Answer (score 1):

You should it rewrite like this:

```
INSERT INTO `cmas` (`transaction_id`)
SELECT `transaction_id`
FROM `transactions` WHERE transactions.property_id IN (select property_id from `cmas`)
```

Problem is there is no select in left part, so expression "transactions.property_id = cmas.property_id" is meaninless, because no selection on cmas is done.

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO cmas (transaction_id)
SELECT transaction_id
FROM transactions,cmas
WHERE transactions.property_id = cmas.property_id
```

Comment: this runs (when I amend the SELECT to `transactions.transaction_id`) but doesnt update the cmas transaction_id

Comment: since this is better solution than mine, i`ll comment here: does query "SELECT transaction_id
FROM transactions,cmas
WHERE transactions.property_id = cmas.property_id"   returns anything?

Comment: it does, it returns the transaction_id